# light box on slick slider and add content to the ligh box pop up with the image

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am getting problem with the slick slider i want to create a light box which should be open on the slick of slick slider i want to add some content in the light box as well the main problem is i don't know how can i add the content to the ligh-box section .

```js
$('.works-slideshow .team-item').each(function() {
  var slider = $(this);
  slider.slick({
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    accessibility: false,
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  var sLightbox = $(this);
  sLightbox.slickLightbox({
    src: 'src',
    itemSelector: '.team-image img'
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-lightbox/0.2.12/slick-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-lightbox/0.2.12/slick-lightbox.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="works-slideshow text-center">
    <div class="owl-item">
      <div class="col-sm-12 mb-sm-20 wow bounceIn">
        <div class="team-item">
          <div class="team-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo" />
          </div>
          <div class="team-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo" />
          </div>
          <div class="team-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo" />
          </div>
          <div class="team-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo" />
          </div>
          <div class="team-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo" />
          </div>
          <div class="team-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="team-descr font-alt">
          <div class="team-name">text</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want if i can show a content div as well with the image as a light-box or pop-up

Answer (score 2):

According to [these examples](https://mreq.github.io/slick-lightbox/demo/), you can declare `data-YOUR_ATTRIBUTE` in your `slickLightBox` html elements, and add it to slickLightBox `option` parameter object as `caption: 'YOUR_ATTRIBUTE'`, to have texts underneath each slide. Hope this solves your problem.

If you want to add more elements, according to @sumitpatel you can put html also into your `data-` attribute like `data-text = '<h2>My heading</h2> <p> My text </p>'` But I think this one is not very readable. I suggest then to pass a function into `caption`, and add multiple attributes to your element. You can check an example in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/n84Ldr1e/)

You can check my example that I edit from your snippet:

```js
$('.works-slideshow .team-item').each(function() {
  var slider = $(this);
  slider.slick({
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    accessibility: false,
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  var sLightbox = $(this);
  sLightbox.slickLightbox({
    src: 'src',
    itemSelector: '.team-image img',
    caption: 'text'
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-lightbox/0.2.12/slick-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-lightbox/0.2.12/slick-lightbox.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="works-slideshow text-center">
    <div class="owl-item">
      <div class="col-sm-12 mb-sm-20 wow bounceIn">
        <div class="team-item">
          <div class="team-image">
            <img data-text="Member photo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo" />
          </div>
          <div class="team-image">
            <img data-text="Member photo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo" />
          </div>
          <div class="team-image">
            <img data-text="Member photo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo" />
          </div>
          <div class="team-image">
            <img data-text="Member photo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo" />
          </div>
          <div class="team-image">
            <img data-text="Member photo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo" />
          </div>
          <div class="team-image">
            <img data-text="Member photo" src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="team-descr font-alt">
          <div class="team-name">text</div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but is there any other way i want to add different elements like heading and p tags etc .

Comment: also you will be able to add your html in to the data-text

Answer (score 2):

This will help you.

```js
$('.works-slideshow .team-item').each(function() {
  var slider = $(this);
  slider.slick({
    arrows: false,
    dots: false,
    accessibility: false,
    infinite: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 600,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          slidesToScroll: 1
        }
      }
    ]
  });

  var sLightbox = $(this);
  sLightbox.slickLightbox({
    src: 'src',
    itemSelector: '.team-image img',
    caption:function(element, info) {
    var span=$(element).parent().find(".desc");
    return span.html(); }
  });
});
```

```css
img {
  width: 95%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-lightbox/0.2.12/slick-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-lightbox/0.2.12/slick-lightbox.min.js"></script>


<div class="row">
  <div class="works-slideshow text-center">
    <div class="owl-item">
      <div class="col-sm-12 mb-sm-20 wow bounceIn">
        <div class="team-item">
          <div class="team-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo" />
            <div class="desc"><h3>Test 1</h3></div>
          </div>
          <div class="team-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo" />
            <div class="desc"><h3>Test 2</h3></div>
          </div>
          <div class="team-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo"  />
            <div class="desc"><h3>Test 3</h3></div>
          </div>
          <div class="team-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo"  />
            <div class="desc"><h3>Test 4</h3></div>
          </div>
          <div class="team-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo" />
            <div class="desc"><h3>Test 5</h3></div>
          </div>
          <div class="team-image">
            <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="Member Photo" />
            <div class="desc"><h3>Test 6</h3></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Just change h3 however you need